# Map on generic array deduces wrong type

Tags: typescript, generics

I've noticed unexpected interaction in the below example. When I try to `map` over the generic `options`, the item inside is not of the type I have expected it to be.

```
const foo = <T extends string[]>(options: T, labels: Record<T[number], string>): string[] => {
    return options.map(o => labels[o]);
}
```

The above example is a simplified problem that in my opinion should be absolutely type safe. Since `labels` is a record of `options`'s index type it must be indexable by it. However, the `map` function says that it's `o` control variable is of type `string`.

Is this because the `map` is incorrectly typed or is this expected behavior?

The simplest workaround I found is to type `(o: T[number]) => ...` but I'm more interested in why this is happening and the theory behind it.

Edit: Example usage

```
foo(["A", "B"] as ["A", "B"], {
    A: "Label A",
    B: "Label B",
})
```

Comment: `o` is a `string` because you defined T as `string[]`. If you want `o` to be a number, it should be T as `Number[]`

Comment: `T` is not a `string[]`, it just extends it. Also nothing in the example has anything to do with numbers.

Comment: "However, the map function says that it's o control variable is of type string." --- what do you expect to see if not a `string` there?

Comment: The `T[number]` type is more specific. When f.e. I set the generic to be `T extends ["A", "B"]` the `o` is deduced to be `"A" | "B"`. Since string literal array like that extends string array shouldn't the map function expect use cases such as this and not just put `string` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a type parameter `T` for the `string` array *items* instead of one for the *array*:

```
const foo = <T extends string>(
    options: T[], labels: Record<T, string>): string[] => {
    return options.map(o => labels[o]);
}

foo(["A", "B"] as ["A", "B"], {
    A: "Label A",
    B: "Label B0",
})
```

[Sample code on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8AVGBTAHlbMAEwhmgCcBLMAcwD4AKAWACgZ2YQAHKS8CAFwwMAbQC6AGhgAbAIYAjbNMEwAStlDkimKRWr0AlEL21xKOjADerDjHLYoAV3JhOPPpAB0AW1lcGSMgWcorKIiBiBgDcrAC+rKwIIAwiAEQAgqlSqQBCqWIwsqRpmdl5klY2HOlCqQAyCkowpVXsObUNoTA5AAxZcQZAA)

> Is this because the map is incorrectly typed or is this expected behavior?

The error at `labels[o]` is expected. In your example, `labels` is a `Record<T[number]>` type, so you can index it with keys of type `T[number]`.

Now, when you invoke `map` on `options`, TS will use the base constraint of `T` (`string[]`) to infer the item type `string` -  this is the best bet of a common base type, we can have here. And `string` is not assignable to `T[number]`,  so you get an error here.

By using a fix key, we can ensure to have the same type for both record keys and array items.

Comment: You didn't explain why `T[number]` works incorrectly, and as I understand this is the core of the question.

Comment: Adding the second `K` argument feels like writing something that is unnecessary but I see now why this problem occurred. I still feel like it's not working as it should but well that's how TS works.

Comment: @MarošBeťko if you declare `<T extends string[]>`, there is no easy way to say, what the actual item type of `T` is and to match this type with `T[number]`. You can reduce your example a bit further by declaring a type parameter only for the item type and omit the array type completely. This should be sufficient for your example, have a look at the edited answer. Cheers